# What makes a logic statement well formed

Tags: logic, solution-verification

So I just started reading How to Prove It and I'm kind of stuck already on chapter 1 :(. The exercise question is 4.

> Analyze the logical forms of the following statements:
> a) Either both
> Ralph and Ed are tall, or both are handsome
> b) Both Ralph and Ed are
> either tall or handsome
> c) both Ralph and Ed are neither tall nor
> handsome
> d) Neither Ralph nor Ed is both tall and handsome.

For a) I thought it was P ∨ Q, with P being Ralph and Ed are tall and Q is Ralph and Ed are handsome.
For c) I wrote ¬(P∧Q) with P and Q being the same as a).

My first question is are my two answers correct?
Also the solution for b) and d) is that they aren't well formed. Why is this? (I feel like b is basically the same as a and d is basically the same as c)?

Comment: Maybe the "atoms" needed are four : Ralph is tall, Ed is tall, Ralph is handsome and Ed is handsome

Comment: What makes you think b) and d) are not well-formed? They are grammatical expressions of English which can be translated into well-formed expressions of propositional logic. (The term "well-formed" is normally only used for formal expressions, not natural language.)

Comment: Then you have to use the connectives to build the composite sentences: "both Ralph and Ed are tall" will be "Ralph is tall $\land$ Ed is tall" and so on

Comment: There is a difference between sentences a) and b): a) asserts that both have the same property, and the "or" is about which property applies to both of them, whereas b) just asserts that each of the two has one of the properties. b) permits for the possibility that Ralph is tall and Ed is handsome, whereas a) does not. A similar pattern applies to c) vs. d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) is not the same as a): If Ralph is tall but not handsome, and Ed is handsome but not tall, then a) is false (it is not true that both are tall, and it is also not true that both are tall) but b) is true it is true that Ralph is either tall or handsome, and same goes for Ed)

Also, c) is not $\neg(P \land Q)$: you can use the same counterexample: Suppose Ralph is tall but not handsome, and Ed is handsome but not tall. Then $P$ and $Q$ are both false, and hence $P \land Q$ is false as well, and that makes $\neg(P \land Q)$ true. But, in this situation, clearly c) is false: c) is saying that Ralph is neither tall nor handsome, and same for Ed, but in this scenario that is not the case.

Finally, note that this very same scenario also shows that c) and d) are not the same. In this scenario, c) is false, but d) is true.

The key to solving all this is as Mauro indicated: you really need *four* atomic statements: one for Ralph being tall, one for Ralph being handsome, and same for Ed. With that, you can carefully distinguish between all these 4 different statements.

Good luck!!